# Concatenate dynamic variables

Tags: powershell, csv, compare

I'm currently working on a powershell script that could compare 2 or more csv files.

So far, the comparing part is all up and working. I now need my users to be able to say which column they'd like to compare beetween the file they've choosen.

I get the user to choose the files using the following :

```
do{

$f1 = Read-Host -Prompt "Selectionez le $i fichier a comparer (mettez le .csv)"
$g1 = Get-Variable -Name $f1
$h1 = $g1.Name
if ($f1 -like $h1) {
    echo "Fichier ok"
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
    cls
    break
    }
echo "Ce fichier n'existe pas"

} while (1)
```

I do this for each files and I check before hand that files exist in the current directory.

Here is the code to read from the user the name of the column they'd like to compare beetween the file they have choosen.

```
$nb = Read-Host -Prompt "How many column would you like to compare ?"

for ($i=0;$i -lt $nb;$i++) {

Clear-Variable -Name col$i -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
Remove-Variable -Name col$i -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
New-Variable -Name col$i -Value (Read-Host -Prompt "Name of the $i column")
Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
$head = Get-Variable -Name col$i -ValueOnly 
$array += "$head"
$header = "$array[$i]"

}
```

My problem is that, in order to parse the csvs' files, I need to get as an output of this loop strings formatted like so :

```
col0.Value;col1.Value;col3.Value...
```

This output will be passed as an argument for a function I wrote that will allow for the position of the column to have no incidence on the comparing part of the script.

Basically, as long as two or more column in at least 2 different csv files match, they'll be compared.

Hope this is clear.

Comment: You should not use (root) variables for this but instead use `PSCustomObject` and use the [`ConvertTo-Csv` cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-csv?view=powershell-6).

Comment: I was not super clear in my description. I don't need the loop output to be a csv file, I need it to be a string that I can pass as an argument of my comparing function later in the script.

Comment: Is your data a proper CSV? Will the comparison always start with the first column then go up to the $nb-th column? Also, will a data field ever have a field delimiter in the data?

Comment: My data are proper csv, the comparaison won't always start at the first column, that's why I created a parsing function, My data field can't have a delimeter in the data, since it's only number.

Comment: If the comparison will not always start at the first field then you must be getting more information from the user correct? Because what you presented makes it sound like it always starts with the first field. That solution is different from the user wanting to compare a random set of fields. What is it that you are actually trying to do? A sequential series of fields? Or a non-sequential set of fields chosen by the user at run time?

Comment: I will update my post to make it clearer but in short, I need my user to pick from the csv file they have choosen to compare which column they want to compare. And For that I made a function that takes the names of the columns as an argument in order to not always start at the first field.

Comment: Basically the pattern would be this: 1) Get the column numbers from the user. 2) Create an ArrayList. 3) Iterate the column numbers from the user adding each column value to the ArrayList. 4) Once they are all in there, use `-join ';'` to create the string. 5) Add that string to another ArrayList that will later be used for the comparison. 6) Move onto the next row, rinse, repeat.

Comment: Ok thank you, I just forot about "-join"